# How to simulate mouse click using C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, simulate, sendinput

I need to simulate a mouse click that clicks on application windows. I'm using Windows.

How can I send a left button mouse click to screen `x, y` coordinates where the window is located?

Answer (score 12):

Use the [SendInput()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) function:

```
INPUT Inputs[3] = {0};

Inputs[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Inputs[0].mi.dx = ...; // desired X coordinate
Inputs[0].mi.dy = ...; // desired Y coordinate
Inputs[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

Inputs[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Inputs[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

Inputs[2].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Inputs[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

SendInput(3, Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Be sure to read the comments in the [`MOUSEINPUT` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273.aspx) regarding how to specify `dx` and `dy` correctly when using `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` in a multi-monitor environment.

Comment: your solution always sends message to 0,0, not to x,y.

Comment: The second and third inputs do not include the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag, so they are relative to the mouse position established by the first input. This is stated in the documentation: "If the MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE value is not specified, dx and dy specify movement relative to the previous mouse event (the last reported position)."  So it is OK that dx and dy are 0 in the second and third inputs.

Comment: For the record, non of the comments tell you how to correctly specify the coordinates.  They hint at it, but you need to experiment a little.

Comment: @Dan as I stated in my answer, the `MOUSEINPUT` documentation explains exactly how to specify the mouse coordinates, eg: "*If MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE value is specified, dx and dy contain **normalized absolute coordinates** between 0 and 65,535. The event procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface; coordinate (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner. **In a multimonitor system, the coordinates map to the primary monitor**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau  You mean the "Remarks" section on MSDN.  And no they dont "EXPLAIN" anything.  You and I may know what y=mx+b is but it is not explained to anyone.  Thats why there are a dozen pages just like this, where the answers are inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to click on (x,y):

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
```

Comment: `mouse_event()` has been superceded by [`SendInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx), you should be using that instead. The documentation you linked to even says so.

Comment: @MustafaChelik Your solution always sends messages to cursor coordinates, not to x,y.