# How to make, Visual studio 2010 c++ mouse click in windows form application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How can i make a mouse click with code? Basicly what I need is to, that the program could find "Class" or "Id" of a button, in MY made browser, and if the code finds required Class or Id the code would press it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of so many other questions it's hard to know which one to choose. Search this site for `[c++][winapi] mouse click`, or read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28386029/62576) (the question is closed, or I'd use it as the duplicate). Search for `[winapi] find window` for locating the class or ID of a control.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be something like:

[FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to "MY made browser"'s window.

[EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494%28VS.85%29.aspx) recursively to iterate through, checking the class with [GetClassName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

[PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to post a [WM_LBUTTONDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to your found button.

Worth mentioning: there are existing tools that do this kind of thing. [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/) is one that I know of, but I'm sure a quick google will find more if you want.