# why can't I send a PostMessage?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
PostMessage(FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("notepad")), WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(160, 140));
```

this code couldn't send an `LBUTTONDOWN`, something wrong?

i can't sure.. maybe it can send `LBUTTONDOWN` but wrong position

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: This guy knows a thing or two. His post may contain some good advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28390315/4581301

Comment: It might be worth adding here that `SendInput` accepts _screen_ coordinates so you will need to retrieve Notepad's window rect and factor that in.

Comment: Call one API function per statement, and check the return value for errors.  If there is an error, call `GetLastError()` for details and print that along with the name of the function that failed

Comment: Even if you succeed posting your message, keep in mind that that it'll be a bad copy of "true" input handling - you are probably not posting the other associated messages, `GetCursorPos` will return incoherent data, and so on. To simulate this stuff way better use `SendInput`.

Comment: No error handling? ``FindWindow`` could have returned ``NULL``

Comment: [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). The same underlying principles apply to mouse input. Your approach is fundamentally flawed, and doomed to fail. This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please explain, what problem you are *really* trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no window with a title of `"notepad"`.  Notepad window titles follow the pattern *`filename`* `- Notepad`
2. `FindWindow` returns `NULL`
3. Because the first parameter of `PostMessage` is zero, the message is delivered to your thread instead of Notepad's window.

You should always check return values from Windows API functions.  When the reason for the failure isn't obvious, the value of `GetLastError()` will give additional clues.

Comment: Notepad's windows are of _class_ "Notepad".  Knowing that should move you another step closer.  Also, last time I looked, the text itself lives in an edit control which is a _child_ of Notepad's main window.  I imagine that's also something you need to allow for.  [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will tell you more - you should learn to use this tool.  But anyway, as commented above, you should probably be using `SendInput()` instead.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Using the class name doesn't get you one step closer. You cannot fake input like that. Using `SendInput` may be an alternative. Or UI Automation. In the vast majority of cases, where people ask for help faking input, the latter is the canonical solution.

Comment: @IInspectable Sure, I mentioned `SendInput` at the end of my comment there.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Sure, and you left out what should be your first consideration for UI Automation. Outside of on-screen keyboards, there's hardly ever a reason to use `SendInput`.